# I need to find the sum of a few numbers which is in a list

Tags: python-3.x

This is how the output should be like :

Enter the expenses: 10 2 5 15

Total: $32

My Code:(it isn't working due to unsupported operant types or smtg like that)

```
Expenses = input("Enter the expenses: ")
List = Expenses.split(' ')
Total = sum(List)
print("Total: $" + str(Total))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your strings into numbers:

```
Total = sum(int(x) for x in List)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `map()` with `sum()` and convert your `List` data into `int`:

```
Total = sum(map(int, List))
```